# Issue with KendoUI update request not using JSON, regardless of dataType: JSON property

Tags: json, node.js, express, kendo-ui, body-parser

I have scoured the KendoUI documentation for the scheduler widget, and have asked this question on the "premium" forums, to no avail.

I am attempting to post meeting data to my NodeJS API. Following the docs, I set up this transport object in my dataSource constructor for update:

```
update: {
  url: "/meeting",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST"
}
```

This is supposed to mirror AJAX object properties. However, the req.params, req.body, and req.query data are all empty. I checked the content of the request body using Fiddler, and it is as follows:

```
_id=56bcab3a2df7994c5a073201&created_by=andrewwimley&case_desc=asdf&creation_timestamp=Thu+Feb+11+2016+09%3A39%3A38+GMT-0600+(CST)&date=Thu+Feb+11+2016+09%3A39%3A38+GMT-0600+(CST)&createdBy=andrewwimley&createDateTime=02%2F11%2F2016+09%3A39+am&endDateString=02-10-2016+11%3A59+pm&startDateString=02-10-2016+12%3A00+am&type=schedule_entry&__v=0&meeting_id=56bcab3a2df7994c5a073201&case_name=asdfFFFF&start_time=Thu+Feb+11+2016+09%3A39%3A38+GMT-0600+(Central+Standard+Time)&end_time=Thu+Feb+11+2016+09%3A39%3A38+GMT-0600+(Central+Standard+Time)&desc=asdf&mediator_LawyerIDs%5B%5D=475840&meeting_result=Manual
```

This is obviously not JSON formatting. Either forcing JSON formatting through KendoUI, or finding a node module that is able to parse this into a JSON object would solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have this in a JSFiddle or KendoUI Dojo example? Also have you checked how the parameterMap is treating your request? Is it calling an update correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John answered with his comment.

Kendo claims the objects under read, update, and destroy mirror the AJAX object. This is clearly not the case as with AJAX you simply need:

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
type: "POST"
```

To make the request body JSON parseable.

KendoUI, however, requires the parameterMap property to be set. Having it configured like so solved my data type issue:

```
update: {
  url: "/meeting", //node rewrite
  dataType: "JSON",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
},
parameterMap: function (data, op) {
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```